# Converted .exe from .jar file with launch4j is not running in another system

Tags: java, jar, exe, launch4j

I have converted a .jar file into an .exe using the launch4j software. But it is running only in my system; if I try to run it in another system it shows the error: "cannot find its launcher file."

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: yup.JVM launcher,..
cannot find the main class:**** program will exit

Comment: @f1sh 
 
yup.JVM launcher,.. cannot find the main class:**** program will exit


why does exe file need jvm to run how to make it run independently

Comment: It's a java application, so you need a jvm to run it. Launch4j provides an embedded JRE containing that jvm, take a look at their website: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @f1sh how to do its configuration please tell me..

Comment: Better explanation, cleanup

Comment: @f1sh i have converted exe using embedded JRE now  it not running my system too